# Can BDOZ and SPDZ implement secure 2-party computation？

Tags: multiparty-computation

Considering that P1 has value x, P2 has value y and they want to compute x+y without telling the other what he has,So P1 and P2 secret-share their values to each other.
Now P1 gets x1 and y1, P2 gets x2 and y2 and they locally compute xi+yi. If P1 want to compute x+y = (x1+y1)+(x2+y2), P2 need to send x2+y2 to P1, but P1 can get x2 by computing x-x1, thus P1 can get y2 and then get the value y, which is P2's private value. This is no doubt a violation of secure.
So my question is, whether BDOZ and SPDZ can implement secure two-way computing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Considering that P1 has value x, P2 has value y and they want to compute x+y without telling the other what he has
> . . .
> thus P1 can . . . get the value y, which is P2's private value. This is no doubt a violation of secure.

If you know $x$ and I have a secret value $y$, and you somehow learn $x+y$, then of course you can deduce $y$. It doesn't matter *how* you learned $x+y$ --- you could learn it from a magic fairy or some cryptographic protocol. The fact that you learn my input is not the cryptography's fault.

When we formalize security of 2PC, we *don't* say "a corrupt party learns nothing about the other party's input." Instead, we say "a corrupt party learns nothing *beyond what can be inferred from the output*." In your example, $y$ can be inferred from $x+y$ (and $x$), so a 2PC protocol doesn't need to hide it. It is impossible to hide $y$ and still let the parties learn $x+y$.

To answer your main question, yes SPDZ and BDOZ work for any number of parties, even 2 parties.